# Filtering a jquery datatable on a TR data-attribute

Tags: html, jquery, datatables, custom-data-attribute

I have a query that is similar, but not the same as, [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458060/is-it-possible-to-filter-a-jquery-datatable-by-data-attribute).

The difference is I'm trying to filter by a data attribute on the row rather than the column. The `tr` element, not the `td` element. This contains a primary key and I'm trying to remove duplicates. Duplicate rows may differ in actual column data, so I can't do it that way. The key is a combination of three numeric fields separated by underscores.

```
<tr data-primarykey="12345678_12_34"><td>...
```

Then, inside a `javascript` function called on page load...

```
  var rows = [];
  $.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex, rowObj, counter ) {
      if(counter === 0) rows = [];

      // I want rowkey to be the data-primarykey attribute of the tr element
      var rowkey = table.row(dataIndex).data('primarykey');

      // If we've seen the row before (already in the array), filter it out.
      // Otherwise, return true and add it to the array
      if ($.inArray(rowkey,rows) > -1) return false;
      else {
        rows.push(rowkey);
        return true;
      }
    }
  );
```

I suspect that part of the problem is that `table` object not being defined anywhere. This filter is applying to multiple tables, so it would need to be whatever table is currently being filtered, if possible. Each table has a unique `id`, but share a `class` attribute.

**Update 2016/12/12**

I have made some progress with a version that uses the actual data attributes. This version has a working `table` DataTable object and I think correctly gets the row and converts it to jquery. However, attempting to get the data-attribute results in `undefined`.

```
$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex, rowObj, counter ) {
      if(counter === 0) rowkeys = [];

      // I want rowkey to be the data-primarykey attribute of the tr element
      var tableID = $(settings.nTable).attr("id");
      var table = $('#'.tableID).DataTable(); // Correct DataTable
      //var row = table.rows(dataIndex).nodes().to$(); // Correct row?
      var rowkey = table.rows(dataIndex).nodes().to$().data("primarykey");
      console.log('key: '+rowkey); // Shows 'key: undefined' in console.

      // If we've seen the row before (already in the array), filter it out.
      // Otherwise, return true and add it to the array
      if ($.inArray(rowkey,rowkeys) > -1) return false;
      else {
        rowkeys.push(rowkey);
        return true;
      }
    }
  );
```

Comment: Are there any errors in your console that indicate that `table` isn't defined?

Comment: No. Only the ajax calls that I use to populate the tables. I tried using `console.log` in the filter, but that doesn't appear either, although if I include it in the page load function, it does. I'm actually thinking that my problem might be that I broke the ajax loading so the tables never get redrawn...

Comment: @jonmrich Are you saying `table` should be available automatically? The documentation on `DataTable.ext.search.push()` is not very comprehensive, and doesn't mention it.

Comment: You need to set the `table` variable.Like this :  `var table = $("#mydatatable").DataTable({ })`

Comment: @jonmrich There are six tables though. The share a css class. It would need to work on all of them. Perhaps: `var table = $(".my_datatable_class").DataTable({ })`?

Comment: I don't think you'll be able to render 6 different tables by using a class attribute.

Comment: I didn't think so. :)

Comment: @jonmirch I can't find any information about what is in the rowObj parameter of the `push(function (settings, data, dataIndex, rowObj, counter)).` other than its an object. Perhaps this contains the `tr` dom object with the data attribute intact. In anycase, I found a work around that solved my own issue. So my interest is now curiosity only.

Comment: @AntonChanning  Could you update your question to give a larger perspective of your page and what you are trying to accomplish.  What I am trying to wrap my head around is why you would have pseudo-duplicate rows (rows that share a common key but have different displayed data).  This has a bit of a code smell to it at the moment.  It is possible we could structure the solution differently so you could have unique rows.  Currently your solution would skip searching a row if another row with a key was checked and since you said the data in the row could be different you could miss a match in ...

Comment: @Aliester It is the other way around. If the key is the same, the row will be the same. But rows with different keys could appear the same, and that would be okay. Technically that would indicate an actual problem in the data that needs resolving. The duplicates that need removing are not duplicates in the database, but rather rows that have been retrieved into the table via more than one route. The table is populated via multiple ajax queries, each acquiring some of the rows. Sorry if that was unclear.

Comment: I have little control over the back end, as the content is generated by a thrid party system with limited scripting capability. Which is why I need to do things in ajax that might under ideal circumstances be performed at the back end.

Comment: At this point I have a solution that works for my employer, as detailed in my answer. But I would like to be able to award the bounty to someone that has a better solution if possible.

Comment: @AntonChanning  Thanks for the clarification.  That makes a lot more sense.  I will see if I can prototype something out for you in the next few days.  I believe we can do this without a "search" function.  I believe we can eliminate duplicates as the data is received with a kind of "upsert" strategy for the table.  Essentially if it is exists replace if it doesn't add.  I would assume that newer data would always take precedence regardless of source.  This way you render unique rows (no dupes in the data) and can search as normal.

Comment: Well, the bounty ends tomorrow if you want the 100rep bonus. All that would be required to get that is the ability to get the value of the data-attribute (of the `tr` preferably, but a '`td` would do) whilst inside the filter.

Comment: @AntonChanning Please clarify me on one thing, I understand you have to remove duplicate rows (combination of 3 chunks of data). Now my question is do you want to remove it on page load? That is those rows should never be part of the table? **or** do you want to remove those rows only on filter operation? Also can you confirm if the dataTable is applied on HTML table or Datatable is built with ajax data?

Comment: @RajshekarReddy The table is empty on page load.  Rows are retreived using `$.get` and then added to the datatable with `table.rows.add($(data)).draw();`. The `draw()` then triggers the filter. My answer below correctly filters the duplicates, but using a hidden column rather than a html5 data-attribute. The only thing I'm stuck on is getting the value of that attribute from within the filter handler.

Comment: @AntonChanning I have that part of `I'm stuck on is getting the value of that attribute from within the filter handler` fixed.. I will give you my answer

Comment: @AntonChanning gave you my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> This filter is applying to multiple tables, so it would need to be whatever table is currently being filtered, if possible. Each table has a unique id, but share a class attribute.

You need to have a `if` check to limit your filter to work on only specified tables.

```
 if (settings.nTable.id === "yourTableId" || settings.nTable.id === "anotherTableId") { 

 }
```

you can also do the `if` check on `class`

```
if ($(settings.nTable).hasClass('yourClass')) { 

}
```

> // I want rowkey to be the data-primarykey attribute of the tr element

You can get that with in the `settings` variable in the callback and using the `counter` variable too in combination.

[image]

So all you need to do is to have this line

```
var rowkey = $(settings.aoData[counter].nTr).data('primarykey');
```

Here is a **[Working example](https://jsfiddle.net/RajReddy/m9j15f2f/2/)** where I use this filter logic.

*Note*: The above example has a static HTML table which I think is not a problem as we are more concentrated on the `filter` logic. Also the filter works only when you type in something in the search box.

So the final logic would look like below

```
var rows = [];

$.fn.dataTableExt.afnFiltering.push(
  function(settings, data, dataIndex, rowObj, counter) {
    if (settings.nTable.id === "yourTableId") {   // change (1)
      if (counter === 0) rows = [];

      // I want rowkey to be the data-primarykey attribute of the tr element
      var rowkey = $(settings.aoData[counter].nTr).data('primarykey'); // change (2)

      // If we've seen the row before (already in the array), filter it out.
      // Otherwise, return true and add it to the array
      if ($.inArray(rowkey, rows) > -1) return false;
      else {
        rows.push(rowkey);
        return true;
      }
    }
  }
);
```

Comment: That works! I didn't need the bit about limiting it to one table, as I wanted to remove duplicate rows from each of the tables. But that might be useful for others. For me, the key part was `$(settings.aoData[counter].nTr).data('primarykey');`

Comment: @AntonChanning glad I could help!! and thanks for the delicious bounty. :D

Comment: With a day to go on that bounty I was beginning to suspect I'd sacrifed a quarter of my rep for a badge. ;)

Comment: @AntonChanning guess it was a luck for both. :)

Answer (score 0):

My efforts to debug this were hampered by my ajax functions only adding the returned rows the table and redrawing if they detected `<tr>` in the results. However, since I'd now changed the opening to `<tr data-primarykey="...">` it was never matching, the rows were never being redrawn and so the filter functions were never called.

Once I had fixed this I started getting an error message `Requested unknown parameter '10' for row 0.` Looking at the [DataTables documentation on this error](https://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4) has left me none the wiser.

I have made a work around that allows me to filter on the key without using the `data-` attribute. I added an extra column to the datatable for the key, and gave the `th` and `td` elements for this column a `css` style that has `display: none;`. I then filtered for duplicates on this column like so...

```
var rowkeys = [];

$.fn.DataTable.ext.search.push(
    function( settings, data, dataIndex, rowObj, counter ) {
      if(counter === 0) rowkeys = [];
      // I want rowkey to be the data-primarykey attribute of the tr element
      var rowkey = data[11] || '';

      // If we've seen the row before (already in the array), filter it out.
      // Otherwise, return true and add it to the array
      if ($.inArray(rowkey,rowkeys) > -1) return false;
      else {
        rowkeys.push(rowkey);
        return true;
      }
    }
);
```

Whilst this answer has solved my problem, and might serve as a good workaround for someone attempting to do something similar, I won't mark it as the accepted answer, because I think a proper answer to this question would be one that was able to use the `data-attribute` in the `tr`.