# Get 'data-sort' orthogonal value from DataTables within search.push function

Tags: datatables, datatables-1.10

I am looping the rows within `$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push` function to select some rows based on many criteria. I am setting some values on the `TD` of the tables known as [orthogonal](https://datatables.net/manual/data/orthogonal-data) data. I am trying to get the value of the **`'data-sort'`** but I don't know how. I am able to get the cell's inner data via `data[2]` (for column 2), but not the 'data-sort' or 'data-filter'. Any ideas?

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {

        var iRating = parseFloat(data[2]) || 0; // this works 
        var datasort = //somehow get the data-sort from the TD
);
```

HTML

```
<td data-sort="57000" class=" seqNum">.....</td>
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like this way I can get the value. If there are any other better ways please advice:

```
$(settings.aoData[dataIndex].anCells[2]).data('sort')
```

Comment: This is how it worked for me on datatables v1.10. I suggest you post this as a full answer to the other question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458060/is-it-possible-to-filter-a-jquery-datatable-by-data-attribute

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is **an easier way**.

The *data* parameter is the "search data" for the row. i.e. the values for "filter" data for each col - not your "sort" data / anything else.

But you also have access to the **full data object for the row** i.e. the 4th parameter - **rowData**.

So you need to use **rowData** at the **index of the column** you want (you say 'for column 2', zero based so - 2 would be for the 3rd column).

Then you should find a **property called 'sort'** :

```
function(settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter){
    var dataSort = rowData[1]['sort'];
    console.log(`This should be the value you want : ${dataSort}`); 
}
```

As per the [documentation here](https://datatables.net/manual/plug-ins/search)