# Datatables search on td attribute

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel, datatables

I've been having issues with searching on the data-search attribute on the table.

This is how I add the attribute via the Datatable():

```
createdRow: function( row, data, dataIndex ) {
  //Check if merchant has psp and add it to the cell
  if(data.parent_id) {
    $( row ).find('td:eq(0)').attr('data-search', 'merchant');
  } else {
    $( row ).find('td:eq(0)').attr('data-search', 'psp');
  }
}
```

I want to use a dropdown to search according to the attribute value, I tried doing it this way:

```
 $('#dropdown1').on('change', function() {
       if(this.value === ' ') {
          table
          .columns( 0 )
          .search( '' )
          .draw();
        } else {
          table
          .columns( 0 )
          .search( this.value )
          .draw();
        }

 })
```

But it just doesn't seem to be working.

Please find fiddle here with mock data https://jsfiddle.net/designtocode/mdfeL7tp/14/

Any help or assistance would be appreciated.

Comment: hi, do you mean you want to let user to select column name in dropdown, and then search by that comumn? like search "ab" on column merchant code?

Comment: @yayapro No I just want the drop down to filter/search the data table with the attributes added. I don’t know if that makes sense?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458060/is-it-possible-to-filter-a-jquery-datatable-by-data-attribute

Comment: The example given in the answer doesn't work. And the other answer is not using an attribute to filter by @yayapro

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could utilize the search-plugin and check directly if the `parent_id` of the row is set depending on the value selected in the dropdown.

This would be the search-plugin:

```
$.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(function (settings, searchData, index, rowData, counter) {
  let shouldDisplay = true;
  let searchValue = $('#dropdown1').val();
  if (searchValue == 'merchant') {
    shouldDisplay = rowData.parent_id ? true : false;
  } else if (searchValue == 'psp') {
    shouldDisplay = rowData.parent_id ? false : true;
  }
  return shouldDisplay;
});
```

And your dropdown just has to call a draw on the table if it changes:

```
$('#dropdown1').on('change', function() {
  table.draw();
});
```