# data tables filter by attribute title,

Tags: jquery, datatables

Im using jQuery datatables and have added some column filters to the table. I have most of the filters working by setting the column defs to html and filtering the text.

however on one field I am using an icon and the text is in the title attribute, I have the column filter selecting the right text to filer on but filtering the table does not work, it shows empty results.

here's a link to a js fiddle reproducing the issue, try filter by the country

Thanks

https://jsfiddle.net/5qn0fovc/

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.5.0/css/flag-icon.min.css">
<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm table-sm dtr-inline" id="site_list" role="grid"
    style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Open Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/sites/site/114/">London</a></td>
            <td><i class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb" title="United Kingdom"></i></td>
            <td>4 Feb 2020</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/sites/site/114/">New York</a></td>
            <td><i class="flag-icon flag-icon-us" title="United States"></i></td>
            <td>10 Augb 2020</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#site_list').DataTable( {
        "pageLength": 15,
        responsive: false,
        "dom": "<'row'<'col-6'l><'col-6'<B><'pull-right'f>>>" +
               "<'row'<'col-12'tr>>" +
               "<'row'<'col-5'i><'col-7'p>>",
        columnDefs: [ 
            {
              targets: 0,
              type: 'html'
           },
           {
              targets: 1,
              type: 'html'
           },                              
        ],
                
        initComplete: function () {
            var excluded_columns = [];
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                if(excluded_columns.indexOf(column.index()) == -1) {
                    var select = $('<br /><select class="dt-select custom-select custom-select-sm" ><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.header()) )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );
                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        });
                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        if(column.index() == 0){ d = $(d).text(); }
                        if(column.index() == 1){ d = $(d).attr("title"); }

                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    });
                }
            });
        },
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: If you want, maybe you can use an alternative like the [data-search](https://datatables.net/examples/advanced_init/html5-data-attributes.html) attribute, or in another solution you can create a hidden element containing the name of the country.

Comment: the data-search worked a treat, Thanks!

Comment: question answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31458060/is-it-possible-to-filter-a-jquery-datatable-by-data-attribute).

Answer (score 0):

In addition to the comment that suggests to use the data-search attribute you can return different values for your columns, based on the render type that you need. You can for example return the complete html string for the display, but only the title attributes value for the filtering:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#site_list').DataTable( {
        "pageLength": 15,
        responsive: false,
        "dom": "<'row'<'col-6'l><'col-6'<B><'pull-right'f>>>" +
               "<'row'<'col-12'tr>>" +
               "<'row'<'col-5'i><'col-7'p>>",
        columnDefs: [ 
            {
              targets: 0,
              type: 'html'
           },
           {
              targets: 1,
              type: 'html',
              render: function(data, type, row) {
                if(type === "filter"){
                    return $(data).attr('title');
                }
                return data;
              }
           },                              
        ],
                
        initComplete: function () {
            var excluded_columns = [];
            this.api().columns().every( function () {
                var column = this;
                if(excluded_columns.indexOf(column.index()) == -1) {
                    var select = $('<br /><select class="dt-select custom-select custom-select-sm" ><option value=""></option></select>')
                        .appendTo( $(column.header()) )
                        .on( 'change', function () {
                            var val = $.fn.dataTable.util.escapeRegex(
                                $(this).val()
                            );
                            column
                                .search( val ? '^'+val+'$' : '', true, false )
                                .draw();
                        });
                    column.data().unique().sort().each( function ( d, j ) {
                        if(column.index() == 0){ d = $(d).text(); }
                        if(column.index() == 1){ d = $(d).attr("title"); }

                        select.append( '<option value="'+d+'">'+d+'</option>' )
                    });
                }
            });
        },
    });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.datatables.net/1.10.19/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/datatables/1.10.21/js/jquery.dataTables.min.js"></script>
<link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/flag-icon-css/3.5.0/css/flag-icon.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-responsive-sm table-sm dtr-inline" id="site_list" role="grid"
    style="width: 100%;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Location</th>
            <th>Country</th>
            <th>Open Date</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/sites/site/114/">London</a></td>
            <td><i class="flag-icon flag-icon-gb" title="United Kingdom"></i></td>
            <td>4 Feb 2020</td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><a href="/sites/site/114/">New York</a></td>
            <td><i class="flag-icon flag-icon-us" title="United States"></i></td>
            <td>10 Aug 2020</td>
        </tr>
    </tbody>
</table>
```